# Add database context to service in configureServices

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to access the database context in a self created service? In the code beneath i want to set the database context with the constructor of the exampleClassService.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Add MVC
    services.AddMvc();

    //Postgres connection
    var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:PostgresConnection"];
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        opts => opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString)
    );

    //Own created service
    services.AddSingleton<ExampleClassService>(
            provider => new ExampleClassService(dbcontext?);  

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In "default" asp.net core:**

If your `ExampleClassService` have constructor like:

```
 public ExampleClassService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
```

then you do not need to add any special factories - this parameter will be injected by DI layer automatically (because you already registered `ApplicationDbContext` earlier), just write `services.AddSingleton<ExampleClassService>()`

If your service have some "special" constructor, then use `provider` param to obtain required dependencies:

```
services.AddSingleton<ExampleClassService>(
    provider => new ExampleClassService((ApplicationDbContext)provider.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

**But!** In your sample you have registration of `ApplicationDbContext` as "scoped" and `ExampleClassService` as "singleton" - are you REALLY sure that you can/may/need use singleton class (single for whole app) `ExampleClassService` that use some other (DbContext) class that you require to be different for each scope/request?

May be you have design errors here, may be ExampleClassService must be "scoped" too or must *not* require DbContext in constructor.

Comment: Thxs for the answer. It works! PS: Interesting note thxs for the advice ;)